# Filter jQuery sortable items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have two div containers that are sortable and connected with `connectWith`. In both there are sortable items that I can drag and drop as intended. These items have some classes, for example, `group1` and `group2`. Let's call containers `container1` and `container2`. I need to make possible `group1` items to be dragged and dropped into any of containers and `group2` items to be dragged and dropped only inside `container2`. I have read jQuery docs but didn't find an answer or an idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try subscribing to the [receive event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-receive). I haven't tested this, but my guess is that if you return false *(the standard pattern for blocking events in jQuery)*, the items dropped won't be added to a list. Here's some pseudo-code to get you started...

```
$("...").sortable(
{
    receive: function ()
    {
        // assuming that "this" maps to the current object being dragged
        if (this.className.indexOf("...")) return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** I've come up with a solution that better answer your needs. This code can be tweaked a bit for example to make the items with `group2` NOT sortable at all, even if they already are in `container1`.

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".container1,.container2").sortable();

    // on mousedown set the "connectWith" option of sortable depending on
    // whenever item that user may start dragging has class "group1" or not
    $(".container1 > li, .container2 > li").mousedown(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parent().sortable("option", "connectWith", $this.hasClass('group1') ? '.connectedSortable' : false);
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="container1 connectedSortable">
    <li class="group1">item 1.1</li>
    <li class="group2">item 1.2</li>
    <li class="group1">item 1.3</li>
    <li class="group2">item 1.4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="container2 connectedSortable">
    <li class="group1">item 2.1</li>
    <li class="group2">item 2.2</li>
    <li class="group2">item 2.3</li>
    <li class="group1">item 2.4</li>
    <li class="group2">item 2.5</li>
</ul>
```